# Data Source Configuration Wizard: Could not retrieve schema information for table or view

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

As the title says, I could not proceed in creating a data source for datagridview. I can see the database and the tables fine, but when I click finish, an error comes up.

What I've done so far:

-Reinstalled MySQL for Visual Studio

-Reinstalled MySQL Connector/NET

-Updated MySQL Updated

-Visual Studio 2017

Any ideas?

BTW I'm using Windows 7 64 bit, Visual Studio 2017 Community, and MySQL 8.0.13. Programming Language is C#

Here's a screenshot.
[Data Source Config Wizard Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb6SR.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the MySQL Visual Studio integration; it has been reported as [bug 92751](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92751).

You can subscribe to updates on that case to learn when Oracle has fixed the bug and released an updated version. As far as I know, there is no workaround.